# Wordpress. Save settings as array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

Could you help, please, to understand how to save the settings correctly in the next case?

```
function my_settings_init() {

    ...
    register_setting( 'my-settings-group', 'my-settings-name' );
    add_settings_field( 'my-field, 'My Field', 'my_field_callback', 'my-plugin', 'my-section' );
    ...

}

function my_field_fallback() {

    $setting = get_option( 'my-settings-name' );
    echo 'input type='text' name='my-settings-name[title]';
    echo 'input type='text' name='my-settings-name[slug]';

}
```

The result array is:

```
Array
(
    [title] => title 1
    [slug] => slug 1
)
```

How to use save_callback to make the next result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => title 1
            [slug] => slug 1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => title 2
            [slug] => slug 2
        )
    ...
)
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to add multiple fields of the same, this can only be done by using [wp_ajax_](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)) hook.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)

Then in your callback you can have a *add new* button to create a new set of fields and an *update* button to save the fields accordingly.

It's better if you save the array as JSON and decode it when you need to append a new array set.